# How do I install the Ask Ubuntu Unity Lens, and how do I use it?

Tags: unity, lenses

I heard about the [Ask Ubuntu Unity Lens](https://launchpad.net/askubuntu-lens) over in the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room), and I was wondering how to install it. What are the step-by-step instructions to get it installed, activated and once that's done, how do I use it?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The Ask Ubuntu Lens is a way to search askubuntu.com via your desktop in Unity. You can search for anything on the site. Questions, tags, users, and badges all show up in the search results and then it will take you here.

Depending on your Ubuntu version:

### For 12.10 and above

[image: Install via the software center]

In 12.10 and above, the Ask Ubuntu Lens is now just a scope of the Help lens, to summon it with a keyboard shortcut use <kbd>Super</kbd>-<kbd>H</kbd>.

### For 12.04 or 11.10:

You can install the **Ask Ubuntu Unity Lens** via the Software Centre by clicking below:

[image: Install via the software center]

You will *need* to **log out and log back in** for the lens to show up and work correctly.

### For 11.04:

You can install the Ask Ubuntu Unity Lens via a PPA

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:askubuntu-tools/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install unity-place-askubuntu
```

Just open up a terminal window and enter the above commands. Then, you *need* to **log out and log back** (or run `unity --replace`) in for the lens to show up and work correctly.

You can click on the Ask Ubuntu icon on your launcher (for 11.04), or inside your dash in 12.04 and 11.10. To get a fully expanded lens or you can hit the <kbd>Super</kbd>-<kbd>U</kbd> keyboard shortcut to summon the lens, then ask your question:

### 12.04 & 11.10 version:

[image]

### 11:04 version:

[image]

You can also right click on the icon and get a quicklist of different sub searches if you only want to search for a specific thing:

[image]

You can find more info [here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/03/unity-askubuntu-lens-installable-via-ppa/).

- Report [bugs here](http://bugs.launchpad.net/askubuntu-lens)

Comment: When I try to run `sudo apt-get install audataserver-proxy` on my 11.10 laptop, it tells me it can't find the package.

Comment: Will there be any possibility to use this in 12.04? I think tighter integration between the ubuntu user community at large and the help/support community will be a huge boon to Ubuntu's continued development.

Comment: I had to remove the tilde from ppa:~markjtully/ppa to add the PPA: ppa:markjtully/ppa

Comment: @DanYes. It facilitates searches here.

Comment: You mean unity-lens-askubuntu?

Comment: We need Ask Ubuntu for 14.04!

Answer (score 10):

#### For 11.04

There are a few special searches you can do. Search for `au` to quickly get a link to Ask Ubuntu (this also works in the global dash). Others are `chat`, for the Ask Ubuntu Chat, `me` (for your recent activity page), `meta`,  and `help` (which will get you to this question).

You can also use the Lens to search any other stackexchange site via @-modifiers. An example search would be:

```
@wordpress file permissions
```

or

```
@so +pygtk about dialog
```

Where @so is short for stack overflow. This is (at the time of writing) the complete list of available sites:

```
@stackoverflow    @serverfault    @superuser       @webapps
@gaming           @webmasters     @cooking         @gamedev
@photo            @stats          @math            @diy
@gis              @tex            @askubuntu       @money
@english          @stackapps      @ux              @unix
@wordpress        @cstheory       @apple           @rpg
@bicycles         @programmers    @electronics     @android
@onstartups       @boardgames     @physics         @homebrew
@security         @writers        @audio           @graphicdesign
@dba              @scifi          @guitars         @codereview
@codegolf         @quant          @pm              @skeptics
@fitness          @drupal         @mechanics       @parenting
@sharepoint
```

Note that the lens will auto-update this list every time you re-boot, so, after your favourite beta site has been launched, it should appear soon.

#### For 11.10

Now that we have scopes, you can just click "Filter Results" and select another Stack Exchange network site.

[image]

Comment: Will this work for sites in private beta as well?

Comment: @jrg I don't think it does due to the way the code uses the API, but I hope one of the authors can verify this.