# Is there a help lens in 11.10?

Tags: unity, 11.10

I read from somewhere about a help lens in the dash with ask ubuntu and othere recommended Ubuntu support sites for users in 11.10. Is this really true or was it a tweak?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an Ask Ubuntu lens:

- [How do I install the Ask Ubuntu Unity Lens, and how do I use it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31712/how-do-i-install-the-ask-ubuntu-unity-lens-and-how-do-i-use-it)

  As far as I can tell there's no general help lens yet, though it would be great if we had one.

Comment: Well Jorge since u work with Canonical, could you please let them know we need a help lens for 11.10? Newbies need to k wo where they can get help right from the dash and not through Google

Comment: Yep, as soon as we have something.

Comment: And I hope I will get the credit for making the suggestion lol..