# Is there an Ask Ubuntu lens available for 11.10?

Tags: unity, 11.10, lenses

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install the Ask Ubuntu Unity Lens, and how do I use it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31712/how-do-i-install-the-ask-ubuntu-unity-lens-and-how-do-i-use-it)

I have been searching around for an Ask Ubuntu lens recently that's compatible with 11.10.

Could anybody give me a hand and either show me how to get one, or tell me when one comes out?