# Can't see installed software

Tags: unity-dash, lenses, scopes

I've install the "Ask Ubuntu Lens" from the software center but it didn't show up is the lenses and I can't search for it as an install app ! What should I do ?

Comment: Type the software name... Btw what software do you installed?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to re-boot your pc and check for Ask Ubuntu Lens, if it doesn't work even after a reboot, Try to remove Ask Ubuntu Lens from Terminal and install it via the Terminal.

Try this with Terminal.

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:askubuntu-tools/ppa

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install unity-lens-askubuntu

Further details on the installation are here - [How do I install the Ask Ubuntu Unity Lens, and how do I use it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31712/how-do-i-install-the-ask-ubuntu-unity-lens-and-how-do-i-use-it)