# How to launch Ask Ubuntu Lens?

Tags: launcher, unity-dash, applications-lens

I have installed Ask Ubuntu Lens on my 12.04 desktop some time back and I could see it in my installed applications from Ubuntu Software Center. But I cannot find it on the dash. How I can launch it ? I installed Alacarte hoping that I can see it there, but could not find it there either.

**Note:** I reviewed the question [on installing lens here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31712/how-do-i-install-the-ask-ubuntu-unity-lens-and-how-do-i-use-it), but could not find answer to my specific question.

Comment: Does `Dash+U`  bring it up , or can you mentioned the installed version (i guess 1.0 is current). Alternately try `unity --reset` and reboot.

Comment: Please show the output of `apt-cache policy unity-lens-askubuntu` to verify that you have installed the lens and from where you did

Comment: $ apt-cache policy unity-lens-askubuntu
unity-lens-askubuntu:
  Installed: 1.0
  Candidate: 1.0
  Version table:
 *** 1.0 0
        500 http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

Comment: Tried unity --reset and rebooted and no luck then. I understand searching some thing from dash, but what and how to use Dash+U?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have logged in after installing the package (as I'm sure James has), you can simply open up the Dash by clicking on the Dock button on the top left of the screen. The dash will open and there will be an icon of a cartoon balloon with "Ask" in it. Mine's in the middle of the set of icons. Each of these icons represent a lens.

Click in it and type "How to launch askubuntu lens". [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/173710/how-to-launch-ask-ubuntu-lens) very question will be in the penultimate row, in Answered Questions (unless you accept my or someone else's answer in which case it will move up a row to "Questions with Accepted Answers").

If you don't see the icon there I'd say there is a bug somewhere.

Comment: Thanks John. I don't see the icon there and that prompted my question