# Lens for Ask Ubuntu in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, lenses

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install the Ask Ubuntu Unity Lens, and how do I use it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31712/how-do-i-install-the-ask-ubuntu-unity-lens-and-how-do-i-use-it)

How do I install Ask Ubuntu lens in Ubuntu 12.10?

Comment: @devav2 not exactly, because that question has no answer for 12.10

Comment: Yes Anwar you are right. Removing my comment.

Comment: This is on-topic.

Comment: @OliveTwist Rather than have this exist as a separate question, the standard way to deal with this situation is to encourage knowledgeable people to add answers to [the existing question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/31712/how-do-i-install-the-ask-ubuntu-unity-lens-and-how-do-i-use-it). A bounty can be offered for this purpose. This is done all the time. So I think we really can (and should) close this as a duplicate of that question.